# Trying to turn on an LED attached to Raspberry Pi via a MCP23017 IO Pi Plus expansion board, using Node modules and javascript only

Tags: javascript, node.js, raspberry-pi, i2c, led

As the title states, those are the tools I'm using. I'm trying to create a single .js file that will turn on/off LEDs (to start with) and that can perform file operations such as

```
-> check value at address 0x20 
-> if 0x20 > x do something
```

I can manually activate LEDs from the command line using

```
i2cset –y 1 0x20 0x12 0xff
```

But I have no idea how to execute these kinds of operations using the node modules and javascript. Also it MUST be javascript, not python/ruby etc.

EDIT: I forgot to mention I already have the i2c and i2c-bus modules installed. Apologies.

Comment: There are multiple packages available on NPM for accessing i2c on a raspberry pi via node.js.  Here's [one](https://www.npmjs.com/package/i2c).  You can find others with an NPM search.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I already have several packages installed, i2c/i2c-bus, and a couple of others. The issue is actually figuring out what the syntax of those packages is. It always seems to me when people write scripts using those packages, they have some kinda of reference library that says "i2c1 = i2c.open(1, function (err) " is a thing, and how that thing works.